# How can I enforce utf8 in the struts1 taglib?

Tags: java, tomcat, utf-8, struts, struts-1

I've got now a the most wonderful task, the dream of all programmers. There is a roughly 15 year old software here, and I only have to fix "some bugs" in it. 32 bit java6, tomcat6, non-unicode source code, ant build system, and everything what I can only "like".

Note, I have power only over a .war file, thus server-side settings aren't okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem lies likely in the `<bean:message>` tag, although also other tags may be problematic.

The Java core supports utf8 since its very early alpha days, but unfortunately there is an exception in the handling of `.properties` files. These files are interpreted always an iso8859-1 by the JDK API calls.

The Struts1 taglibs use i18n strings addressed by keys, stored in `*.properties` files. Digging a little bit into the struts1 source, I've found these:

- It reads the `.properties` files with the JDK calls, thus always in iso8859-1. It is deeply hardwired into the code, there is no way to change it.
- There is a *locale* or *localeKey* parameter in the struts 1, which can be changed by various `system.properties` or `web.xml` settings, the `.properties` will be still read always as iso8859-1. This locale/localekey only adds an extra extension to the actually interpreted properties file.
- There is no way to change it, without forking/duplicating the corresponding part of the struts1, *and* enforcing some non-standard thing into the JDK Properties headers to enforce the standards to their conventions. It is not a very convenient thing in the case of such a relic code.

Although the struts and the other parts of your system (for example, the JSP parser/interpreter) *does* already some conversion as needed, so this iso8859-1 text *will* be converted to utf8, if your JSP pages are correctly set up (meta headers and so on).

Furthermore, the property reader uses a - similarly hardwired, undisable - feature, to have a little support for utf8. It accepts utf8 characters in the form `\uC0DE`. Thus, after a `\u` or `\U` (case insensitive), you can give a 16-bit hexa value, which *can be* and unicode character.

It has to be always 16 bit long, other lengths are not allowed, but these are already case insensitive.

Thus,

```
my.property.key=árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
```

...encoded as utf8, won't work, it will be interpreted as iso8859-1.

You can enter this string as iso8859-1. It can't work, because some of the accents don't have an iso8859-1 mapping, i.e. they don't exist in the iso8859-1 encoding.

However, if you encode it into the above described format:

```
my.property.key=\u00E1rv\u00EDzt\u0171r\u0151 t\u00FCk\u00F6rf\u00FAr\u00F3g\u00E9p
```

then yes, it will work!

To do this conversion, the Sun had a `native2ascii` tool, which is unreachable today. You have to dig this tool from some archive on the net, or find a different one.

On Linux, there is a tool named `uni2ascii` (on debian-based distributions, you can install it with `apt-get install uni2ascii`), which does the correct conversion. The correct parameters are:

```
uni2ascii -a U myfile.properties
```

The result goes to the stdout.

It is up to you, how do you integrate it into your build system (some ant/maven exec module, or simply use it on change every time, manually).

Comment: Don't blame Struts for `Properties`. They've always been `ISO-8859-1` and that's Java's fault.

Comment: Well, not Java's *fault* per se. During those times UTF-8 wasn't as widely propagated as it is today, so it was thought as a "safe" alternative to use a single character encoding. Still, it has caused mainly annoyance.

Comment: @Kayaman Working for safety is okay, but they actually *switched off* utf-8 support, contrary to the standards, contrary that they knew, it is an upcoming one, and contrary that *all of their already written code was built on utf8 from the beginning*. They ignored not only the standards, they ignored also their own conventions.

Comment: The encoding of property files is a different thing from Java's support for unicode. Back then you'd have source files in different encodings too, something that should be quite rare these days. While Java was designed to support unicode from the beginning, it didn't mean that the world around it would be in unicode yet. That's why they made the whole unicode escapes in property files thing.

Comment: @Kayaman Your explanation is acceptable until the point, that they made something not-working what is a central point in their whole previous work. If a simple, utf-8 encoded properties file could work, I wouldn't have any problem with their solution, independently how tricky other filters/contraints they inserted into it. I find it an aggrevating circumstance that they didn't add even later, although they surely faced this problem in customer feedbacks. They said, *here is this native2ascii tool*, which is a typical big company reaction to avoid a real fix of a real problem.

Comment: I don't know if you developed Java back when this was an issue, but I did. The `native2ascii` tool was not some workaround given out because of customer feedback. It was a standard tool included because there was no such thing as "simple UTF-8 encoded properties". UTF-8 was weird and new back then, not the kind of standard it is these days. I understand you're frustrated having to maintain legacy code, I would be too, but you seem to misunderstand the reasoning behind the whole thing. They wanted to avoid the corruption of files, because `ISO-8859-1` was the "standard" encoding back then.

Comment: @Kayaman I remember in these old times, I converted our Linux webserver to full utf8-only (well), but it was incompatible with the winscp of my boss. He used the terminology *"your m\*\*\*d utf8"* to describe his vision about my changes :-) However, as I started my Java, the most feasible way to solve any encoding problem was already to convert anything to unicode what isn't done yet. I have no idea, what did people do whose languages use mainly non-iso1 characters (like Russian). Maybe they used an unicode .properties in the source, and executed the native2ascii as part of their compilation.

Comment: @Kayaman Btw, I think a `##encoding: utf-8` as the first line of the `.properties` had been a correct solution to the problem, where this line had been indentified by the `##` prefix. With some polimorphic interpretation, it could have worked also with non ascii7-compatible encodings (mainly ebcdic).

Comment: @Kayaman I removed the blaming part, but not because I don't think they wouldn't deserve it in this case. I did it because I like Java and their work.